# Auto-Fit Canvas element

Tags: qt, canvas, html5-canvas, qml

I'm working with Qt 5.4. I have a Qt Quick Project and I'm using QML. For some reasons I have to use the `Canvas` element to draw a tree. In some cases, my tree is larger than my Canvas element (`400x800`). So, my question is: how can I auto-fit my canvas depending my tree height?, there is a scrollbar or something like that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your `Canvas` inside `ScrollView` or `Flickable`, for example:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 200;
    height: 200;
    id: root
    ScrollView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Flickable {
            anchors.fill: parent
            contentWidth: canvas.width
            contentHeight: canvas.height
            Canvas {
                id: canvas
                width: 300
                height: 300
                property int maxX: 0
                property int maxY: 0
                property var coords: getCoords()

                function getCoords() {
                    var retval = [];
                    for(var i = 0;i < 10;i ++) {
                        var x = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
                        var y = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000);
                        retval.push(x);
                        retval.push(y);
                    }
                    return retval;
                }

                onPaint: {
                    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    context.fillStyle = "white";
                    context.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
                    context.moveTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
                    context.strokeStyle = Qt.rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
                    context.lineWidth = 5;
                    context.beginPath();
                    for(var i = 0;i < coords.length;i += 2) {
                        context.lineTo(coords[i],coords[i + 1]);
                        if(coords[i] > maxX) maxX = coords[i];
                        if(coords[i + 1] > maxY) maxY = coords[i + 1];
                    }
                    context.closePath();
                    context.stroke();
                }
                onPainted: {
                    if(canvas.width < maxX || canvas.height < maxY) {
                        canvas.width = maxX;
                        canvas.height = maxY;
                        update();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Remove `ScrollView` item if you need only `Flickable`. The `Canvas` updates itself to max width/height.